# How to redirect custom domain to my project domain

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I was trying to build a URL shortener.
My primary domain is `makemyshortener.com`
But as i need to make URL shortener i need to make my URL short 
so after shortening the main url it's converted to `mms.com/eer22`
My problem is whenever user click on the shortened link i.e. (mms.com/eer22) how to check it with my main domain database?

Answer (score 0):

Get the shortened parameter(eer22) using htaccess. In database connect statement, give primary domain as your host instead of localhost and use its credentials and database name. Compare and redirect.